# Concatenate values of dictionary of list with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, concatenation

I want to extract values A, C, D and E (I don't need value_B, which is a number) from the following dictionary:

```
{'key1': [{'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': value_B}, 
         {'key_A': 'value_C'},
         {'key_A': 'value_D'},
         {'key_A': 'value_E'}],
'key2': True}
```

Then I want to concatenate those values into a single string with a new line between each value.
Like so:

```
string = ''
for value in values:
    string += value + '\n'
```

Or maybe this:

```
string = ''
string = '\n'.join(values)
```

What I want is this:

```
string = 'value_A' + '\n' + 'value_C' + '\n' + 'value_D' + '\n' + 'value_E'
```

What's the best approach to do this? How would I go about doing it?
I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `key_A` and not `{'key1': [{'key_A': ['value_A', 'value_C', 'value_D', 'value_E'], 'key_B': 'value_B'}], 'key2': True}`?

Comment: {'key_A': 'value_C'} is one dictionary inside a list that's the value of another dictionary. {'key_A': 'value_D'} is a different dictionary that is another element of that list. Is that not possible?

Comment: Based on the discussion on our post I'd recommend that you [edit] this so that it's clear that you don't know the actual keys of the inner dicts before run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do this in a one liner, I'd recommend decomposing your problem into smaller sub-problems.

```py
my_string = '\n'.join(e['key_A'] for e in my_dict['key1'])
```

You have a dictionary in which one of the keys contains a list of dicts. You want to end up with a string containing the value of 'key_A' from every dict in the list of dicts separated by '\n'.

To me the obvious steps are:

1. Select the list of dicts from 'key1' of the parent dict.
2. Collect the values of 'key_A' from the list of dicts
3. Join the values together in a string separated by a '\n'

```py
# Select the list of dicts from the parent dict
my_list_of_dicts = my_dict['key1']

# Select the 'key_A' value from each dict in the list
my_values = [e['key_A'] for e in my_list_of_dicts]

# Join the values together into a string separated by the '\n'
my_string = '\n'.join(my_values)
```

If you don't know what key to use until runtime, and you are confident that the first key will be the desired key. You can either derive the key in advance and store it or derive it for each individual dict.

```py
# Derive the key in advance
# Get the first key of the first dict stored in my_dict['key1']
my_key = list(my_dict['key1'][0].keys())[0]
my_string = '\n'.join(e[my_key] for e in my_dict['key1'])

# Derive the first key for every dict
my_string = '\n'.join(e[list(e.keys()[0])] for e in my_dict['key1'])
```

Comment: You don't need a list for ```join```. ```join(e['key_A'] for e in my_dict['key1'])```

Comment: @Sujay Thanks! I always forget that quirk of the language.

Comment: I'm trying to do this: ```my_list_of_dicts = my_dict[list(my_dict.keys())[0]]``` because I want the first value of dict, whatever the key may be, and the resulting string is just value_A concatenated a bunch of times. value_C, D and E don't appear. What am I doing wrong? Should I edit the question and show my updated code?

Comment: Instead of using a snipped of code to describe what you're trying to do, (since if it worked, you wouldn't need to be asking for help), can you try to describe what you're trying to do in English?

Comment: I want a string that is ```'value_A' + '\n' + 'value_C' + '\n' + 'value_D' + '\n' + 'value_E'```. But I tried to implement the code above and now I'm only getting a string that's ```'value_A' + '\n' + 'value_A' + '\n' + 'value_A' + '\n' + 'value_A```. Am I being clearer or should I try to elaborate more? Genuine question.

Comment: The code I wrote will produce the string `"value_A\nvalue_C\nvalue_D\nvalue_E"`. It seems to me that your problem with it is that you don't know what key to use before runtime.

Comment: @LailaCampos I've updated my answer with two separate strategies for deriving a key at runtime.

Comment: I tried the updated answer and now I get the error ```TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable```. I'm sorry, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to cast the result of `dict.keys()` to a list to be able to access elements in order. I'll update the code.

Comment: I deleted my code and implemented your solution from scratch and it worked. I must have been doing something wrong before. Thank you. I'll mark it as the solution.